# Paratest, possible to test a specific function?

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

I run tests against a user Module using this command

```
./vendor/bin/paratest -pauto modules/User
```

That runs each test within the modules/User/Tests folder

I want to run a specific function in a specific file within the modules/User/Tests file

path would be: modules/User/Tests/UserTest.php

the function I am aiming to test is:

```
function testUserSearch() { }
```

I just want to test testUserSearch

Is there a way to do it using paratest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With paratest you can use the "filter" & "functional" options to test class or method:

> ./vendor/bin/paratest --functional --filter=testUserSearch